# neo4j graphql mutating with empty array

Tags: list, neo4j, graphql, nullable, apollo-server

I am new to graphql and the neo4j graphql library and could use some help.
My aim is to create an optional `tags` fields to `BlockTitle`

I have the following schema:

```
type BlockTitle  {
    id: ID! @id 
    created_at: DateTime! @timestamp
    text: String!
    tags: [Tag!]! @relationship(type: "HAS_TAG", direction: OUT)
 }

type Tag {
    id: ID! @id 
    created_at: DateTime! @timestamp
    name: String! @unique
 }
```

in the neo4j graphql docs I red the following:

> The relationship at User.posts is considered a "many" relationship. Relationships such as the one above should always be of type NonNullListType and NonNullNamedType, meaning both the array and the type inside of it should have a !.
> [neo4j doc ref](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/type-definitions/relationships/)

Honouring the recommendation I made the tags field accordingly: `tags: [Tag!]! ...`

But I have trouble mutating the following item (with a tag) in apollo studio:

```
mutation CreateBlockTitles($input: [BlockTitleCreateInput!]!) {
  createBlockTitles(input: $input) {
    blockTitles {
      text
    }
  }
}
```

with input

```
{
  "input": {
    "text": "A title without a tag"
  }
}
```

which returns following error

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "BlockTitle.tags required",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
    ...
```

The things I tried / considered:

1. supplying an empty array `[]` for the tags field in the mutation but I fail to make that work. I still get the error.
2. using `[Tag]` instead of `[Tag!]!`, but going against the recommended practice. So do not really want to do that.

Thank you for the help <3

Comment: Hi, could you add your current `@neo4j/graphql` version? This could be a bug in that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, this was a bug that was fixed in 2.5.3. I've just tried the Mutation and input given above with the code for the current 3.0.1 release, and everything seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for that. That indeed was the culprit.